# Is there a way to have getSystemService() return a completely new instance every time in Android?

Tags: android, android-sensors, sensormanager

In Android Wear, registering and unregistering SensorEventListeners repeatedly with a SensorManager causes the SensorManager to fail. I'm wondering if there is a way that I can get a new instance of SensorManager every time I load my fragment. So that I can get a new SensorManager, register my listeners, and unregister them when the fragment is destroyed, and then de-reference that SensorManager and get a new one the next time the fragment is loaded.

In my fragment I am currently doing this:

```
@Override
public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // ... 
    mSensorMgr = (SensorManager) mMainWearActivity.getSystemService(Activity.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    // ...
}

private void startListening(){

    yGesture.setOnShakeListener(yListener);
    xGesture.setOnShakeListener(xListener);
    mSensorMgr.registerListener(yGesture, mSensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    mSensorMgr.registerListener(xGesture, mSensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    startListening();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    stopListening();
    super.onPause();
}

private void stopListening(){

    mSensorMgr.unregisterListener(yGesture);
    mSensorMgr.unregisterListener(xGesture);
    mSensorMgr = null;
}
```

I need `mSensorMgr = (SensorManager) mMainWearActivity.getSystemService(Activity.SENSOR_SERVICE);` to return a new instance, otherwise registering and unregistering listeners multiple times makes the SensorManager fail. Is this possible? Preferably without having to make a new Activity and just stick to using fragments. Thanks

EDIT:

I've moved registering the listeners with the sensorManager to onResume(), and yet the same problem still persists. Is this a bug in the Android Wear framework?

Comment: Why  you are not doing  startListening(); in `onResume()` if you do stopListening() in `onPause()` ?

Comment: @Boris_Treukhov OnCreateView() is called before onResume() in the Fragment lifecycle, so I just call it there once the view is being created instead of a couple of methods down the line. It makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you always want to use correctly paired Activity or Fragment lifecycle methods to register and unregister listeners of any kind.  So you would use create/destroy, or start/stop, or resume/pause.

In your particular case, you are registering in onCreateView, which is called *only* once for a fragment instance, however, your unregister is happening during onPause, which could be called multiple times.  As soon as this fragment is paused for any reason (and there are a lot of reasons this could happen), your listeners are forever gone until a new instance of the fragment is created.

So you might want to consider using create/destroy or start/stop depending on what exactly you're trying to do with the listener in your fragment.  If you don't understand these lifecycle methods, please study it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).

Comment: Is onCreateView() called only once for a fragment even if it is put on the backstack or replaced? I thought that if the fragment was replaced, it would have it's view destroyed, and then once it was popped from the backstack it's view would be redrawn using onCreateView() - > onViewCreated()? I need to unregister listeners when the fragment is replaced, and register them again when the fragment is popped from the backStack, so what methods would I use for that?

Comment: If the fragment gets destroyed for some reason, all the views are going to be made invisible and left for garbage collection.  The official docs give a visualization of what can happen: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating

Answer (score 1):

> Is there is a way that I can get a new instance of SensorManager...?

No. The object returned by `getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE)` is basically an interface object to a system-level service.  There is only one instance of that service on the device.

You can get some insights into what the `SensorManager` service is doing by creating an Android Studio `logcat` filter with selected tag "SensorManager" and Debug level.  The filter will enable output such as this:

```
D/SensorManager: registerListener :: 6, CM3323 RGB Sensor, 200000, 0,
D/SensorManager: unregisterListener ::
```

Looking at this output might help you see something unexpected in the way you are registering and unregistering your listeners.

It is not good practice to register your listeners in `onCreateView()` and unregister in `onPause()`.  When the fragment's activity gets paused and resumed, the fragment is also paused and resumed with no call `onCreateView()`.  This is explained in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle).

You might also try experimenting with slower sensor update rates.  `SENSOR_DELAY_GAME` is 20 milliseconds, maybe faster than you need for your application.  `SENSOR_DELAY_UI` is 67 milliseconds, `SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL` is 200 milliseconds.

Comment: I never even thought about changing the delay. I'll change where I register/unregister and play about with the delay to see if that helps, thanks for the help.